# How to split docker layers into smaller files (when uploading)?

Tags: docker, upload

I have a dockerfile that creates around 7 layers, but some of them are around 500MB.

I was wondering how to split that 500MB layer into many smaller ones 50MB let's say so when I upload and the connection fails doesn't fail 500MB layer, but just a 50MB layer.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker layers correspond to Dockerfile instructions that are executed upon build. Each layer size is determined by the amount of read/writes that the instruction performs.

To reduce the layer size, identify the layer that has the 500MB size, and find the corresponding instruction inside the Dockerfile. Try to split this instruction into multiple instructions so that you get smaller layer sizes.

Comment: The instruction is `yarn install`, so I doubt is possible. I still want to split this layer in multiple layers, in a generic way if possible.

Comment: @Totty.js You can reduce it into to yarn install commands by splitting the packages being installed between the two commands.

Comment: How do you do that? I mean in a proper way without having to manually copy paste different parts of my lock or package.json file? 
Anyway I'm not sure that is the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

There is really no substitute for splitting the packages list into multiple chunks and running multiple, nearly duplicate RUN statements processing one chunk at a time, performing partial installations of smaller chunks of packages list to obtain multiple smaller layers in your container. The installation process will not be much faster, but the subsequent security scans and docker push definitely will.

Installing from lists of packages in files works for bash (apt/yum) and python (pip/conda) installers, but your mileage may vary in other languages.

But it gets more interesting in this particular use case, i.e. when installing packages, because they have dependencies, which leads to unexpected growth (e.g. 10-20-fold) of the chunks installed earlier (while chunks installed later will likely re-use the same dependencies from previously installed chunks, and include packages already installed as depdendencies, so they will end up smaller than intended).

Therefore it's advisable to use a geometric series of chunk sizes (e.g. constructed with `np.geomspace()` and fed into `more_itertools.split_into()`) if you really must have (roughly) equal-sized container layers (as opposed to a 10-20-fold range of chunk sizes).